# Is it possible to build an OLTP/CRUD HTTP server using AkkaHttp, AkkaStreams, Alpakka and a database?

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http, alpakka

It is clear to me that using Actors of course it is possible: for instance https://github.com/chbatey/akka-http-typed.git is using AkkaHttp and typed actors.

But it is unclear to me if just using AkkaStreams and its Alpakka connectors library (which includes databases), if is it possible to do regular CRUD / OLTP services, or just data replication from one database to another, or other OLAP / batch / stream processing scenarios.

If you know how it can be done please indicate a few details and if you can provide an example on github for instance that would be great.

The way I am thinking it may be possible is that the server is involved in two conversations / stateful stream transformation: one with the outside world over HTTP, and one with the database. I am not sure if this is possible to be modelled like that.

https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/slick.html seems to offer both UPDATE/INSERTS as a Sink as well as pointed SELECT to a certain id as a Source. Do you know if an example app is there or can you broadly mention how the wiring would happen with Akka Http?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put a demo here, hope it can help you.

Creating table, database is mysql.

```
CREATE TABLE test(id VARCHAR(32))
```

sbt:

```
"com.lightbend.akka"                        %% "akka-stream-alpakka-slick"     % "1.1.0",
"mysql"                                      % "mysql-connector-java"          % "5.1.40"
```

Code:

```
package tech.parasol.scala.crud

import java.sql.SQLException

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives.{complete, get, path, _}
import akka.stream.alpakka.slick.scaladsl.{Slick, SlickSession}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink
import akka.stream.{ActorAttributes, ActorMaterializer, Supervision}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.io.StdIn
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object CrudTest1 {


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    implicit val system = ActorSystem("CrudTest1")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher




    val hostName = "120.0.0.1"
    val rocketDbConfig =
      s"""
         |db-config {
         |  profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$$"
         |  db {
         |    dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource"
         |    properties = {
         |      driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         |      url = "jdbc:mysql://${hostName}:3306/rocket?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useSSL=false"
         |      user = "root"
         |      password = "passw0rd"
         |    }
         |  }
         |}
         |
     """.stripMargin


    implicit val session = SlickSession.forConfig("db-config", ConfigFactory.parseString(rocketDbConfig))


    import session.profile.api._

    def persistence(message: String) = {
      def insert(message: String): DBIO[Int] = {
        sqlu"""INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (${message})"""
      }

      session.db.run(insert(message)).map {
        case _ => message
      }.recover {
        case e : SQLException => {
          throw new Exception("Database error ===>")}
        case e : Exception => {
          throw new Exception("Database error.")}
      }

    }


    val route = path("hello" / Segment ) { name =>
        get {
          val res = persistence(name)
          onComplete(res) {
            case Success(value) => {
              complete(s"<h1>Say hello to ${name}</h1>")
            }
            case Failure(e) => {
              complete(s"<h1>Failed to say hello to ${name}</h1>")
            }
          }
        }
      }

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8088)

    println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8088/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
    StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
    bindingFuture
      .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
      .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically at every request receive in AkkaHttp, we create an AkkaStreams Graph (just a pipeline typically), basically just the Slick Alpakka Source from the database, maybe prefixed by some operators, and then returned in AkkaHttp, which of course supports Source. More details at [https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-build-an-OLTP-CRUD-HTTP-server-using-Akka-HTTP-Akka-Streams-Alpakka-and-a-database-Do-you-know-any-examples-of-code-on-GitHub-or-elsewhere/answer/Nicolae-Marasoiu]